# Allocating memory space from python3 and pass the pointer to C

Tags: python, python-3.x, pointers, memory, heap-memory

I have built a library consists of python layer and C++ layer. In the C++ layer I have a big chunk of memory that I need to keep in the heap so the chunk has to be allocated dynamically at the time of compilation.

What I want to do is to make this chunk of memory configurable from the python side. Is there a way to allocate memory space dynamically from python and pass the pointer to C++ layer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use ctypes byref or pointer

to dynamically allocate memory you can create a variable or an array in Python
(preferably use data types provided by ctypes)
then you can pass the pointer to the C++ layer through a function or so

see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) library to make DLL/shared libraries calls.

**Windows:**

```
import ctypes
dwFlags = ctypes.c_int(0x00000008) # HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY
szSize = 256 # Size of the area you want to allocate

addr = ctypes.windll.kernel32.HeapAlloc(ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetProcessHeap(), ctypes.c_int(dwFlags), ctypes.c_int(szSize))
```

Now the variable `addr` holds the address of the memory allocated

Comment: Thank you. But it looks like this is os dependent. I guess there is no universal way to create memory from python, which works for both windows and linux.